# Changing Command Prompt Text Size C++

Tags: c++, winapi, command-prompt

I developed a console application in C++ that will run only on Windows. I want to change Command Prompt's text size when the program runs. I did some search but, I could not find anything that would solve the problem. Everybody is just talking about changing the color.

Anyway, if this is possible, how can I change the text size of Command Prompt.

Thank you!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You are confusing the application you develop with the console by itself. The console is a terminal running an interpreter with input and outputs. The outputs can contain ANSI terminal codes translated to color, but the display of text belongs to the terminal itself. The question is related to C++ only if you have to develop your own console, that is, if the text size is mandatory in your specifications. Otherwise, I don't know of any arguments to be passed to the console.exe to configure the text size. You may look for alternative to the default console such as powershell.

Comment: But I can change its windows size or its text color. Nevertheless, I could not change the text size. It is just bad...

Comment: [Win32 console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_console) font sizes is directly dependent on its size.
See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/192c888a-2994-48aa-bb17-ec95f03535b0/how-to-use-graphic-class-in-visual-c-console-application) code.

Comment: Thank you boleto, your comment solved the problem.

Answer (score 4):

You have to initialize CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX structure with sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX) before getting current font info.
Also you have to use only available sizes:

- 4 x 6
- 16 x 8
- 6 x 9
- 8 x 9
- 5 x 12
- 7 x 12
- 8 x 12
- 16 x 12
- 12 x 16
- 10 x 18

```
BOOL SetConsoleFontSize(COORD dwFontSize){
    HANDLE output = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX info{sizeof(CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX)};
    if (!GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(output, false, &info))
        return false;
    info.dwFontSize = dwFontSize;
    return SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(output, false, &info);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX` struct to specify the parameters of the text/formatting of your command prompt writes.

For more information, click [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/28014/#msg150608).

Extract from above link.

> here's a full example. I can't say if it works, because apparently functions Get/SetCurrentConsoleFontEx are only available in windows vista and later.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

int main(){
    HANDLE outcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);//you don't have to call this function every time

    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX font;//CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX is defined in some windows header
    GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(outcon, false, &font);//PCONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX is the same as CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX*
    font.dwFontSize.X = 7;
    font.dwFontSize.Y = 12;
    SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(outcon, false, &font);

    SetConsoleTextAttribute(outcon, 0x0C);
    std::cout << "I'm red";
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A console application is not the same thing as a GUI application. The provided link describes another problem altogether.

Comment: I tried `CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX`; however, it does not change anything.

Comment: How about this: For a detailed discussion see the MSDN documentation for [`SetCurrentConsoleFontEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200.aspx). (Vista and above only)