# How to print larger unicode characters

Tags: java

Essentially im creating a blackjack game and im using the unicode cards for my program but the output for the cards is just to small so i was wondering if there was any way to make them bigger like by pringing 1/4 of the card four times any help is appreciated.

Comment: How / where are you outputting the characters?

Comment: Into windows 10 cmd

Comment: Please show us the code.  Your answer is too vague.

Comment: there is no code simply when i take a surrogate pair denoting one of the unicode cards such as this and print it. The card is to small to read in the console so i was wondering if theirs a way to enlarge it. System.out.println("\uD83C\uDCAA");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, when you write characters to a console (such as CMD) they are displayed using the font and character size selected by the user.

The user can typically change the font and character via the console tool's settings, etcetera.  However, there is nothing that a pure Java application<sup>1</sup> can do to change the console's character size, and certainly not on a per-character basis.

If your game is going to output those characters, you should probably be using an GUI or a web browser to display the output.

---

<sup>1 - If you are willing to write native code and call it from Java via JNI or JNA, it is apparently possible to change the current console's character size; see [Changing Command Prompt Text Size C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114395/changing-command-prompt-text-size-c).  Note that this only works on MS Windows.</sup>